How can i get the Value property of a response from Powershell?
I make a REST call using Powershell and get a response of the following:
 {
  "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#directoryRoles",
  "value": [
   {
     "DateTimeVal": null,
     "Name": "Foo Administrator",
    "id": "09fe6ef5-4af5-650d-a2e5-63895bba8f16",
  },
   {
  "DateTimeVal": null,
  "Name": "Bar Administrator",
  "id": "1602300e-a17b-42d0-97a2-e3d0f0c1fa14",
},    
[...]

How can I get the value and traverse each record in the array?
